# Lower bound for Degenerate Codes?

Tags: error-correction

According to ([Macchiavello, Palma, Zeilinger, 2001; pg82](https://books.google.es/books?id=6hBq7Un57R0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)) a lower bound of the encoding Hilbert space of a *non degenerate code* is given by the quantum version of the [Hamming bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound):
$$2^k \sum_{i=0}^t 3^i \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i\end{pmatrix}\le 2^n$$
where we are looking at a $[n,k,2t+1]$ code. Does such a bound exist for a degenerate code? and why is it different (if it indeed is)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This bound works by counting the number of orthogonal states that must be available. If you're encoding into $n$ qubits, you can't require more than $2^n$ orthogonal states, because that's all that's available. This is the right hand side of the bound.

If you wish to encode $k$ logical qubits in a distance $2t+1$ code, then each of the $2^k$ basis states of those logical qubits must encode to something different. Moreover, you need to be able to correct for up to $t$ errors of type $X$, $Y$ or $Z$. If we require each of these to map to a different orthogonal state, then there are $3n$ possible 1-qubit errors, $3^2\binom{n}{2}$ 2-qubit errors (choice of one of 3 Paulis for each error, and a pair of locations for them to happen at), and so on. So, this gives the stated bound, known as the Quantum Hamming bound (also Gilbert-Varshamov). However, an essential feature of the derivation is the assumption that each error is mapped onto a different orthogonal state.

The very definition of a degenerate code is that multiple errors can be mapped onto the same state. As a trivial example, consider the effect of a single-qubit $Z$ error on any one of the qubits of the GHZ state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle^{\otimes n}+|1\rangle^{\otimes n}).
$$
No matter where that error happens, the resultant state is the same, but that's fine: I don't need to be able to identify which of the $n$ qubits the error happened on to fix it. Once I know the error has happened, I can apply a $Z$ gate on any of the qubits that I choose in order to fix it. (I don't claim that this example enables you to detect that error.) So, **the Quantum Hamming bound does not apply to degenerate codes**. Indeed, there are known examples where the bound is beaten, e.g.  [D. P. DiVincenzo, P. W. Shor, and J. A. Smolin, Phys. Rev. A 57, 830 (1998)](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.57.830) ([free version](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9706061)), although there are surprisingly few.

The only replacement that I know of is the Quantum Singleton Bound, $n-k\geq 4t$. The Quantum Hamming bound, in practice, appears to give very good estimates of what can be achieved, but is not absolute when it comes to degenerate codes.