# Famous qutrit codes with no qubit analogue

Tags: error-correction

No $ [[3,1,2]] $ qubit code exists (more generally no $ ((3,2,2)) $ qubit code exists). See [Why can't there be an error detecting code with fewer than 4 qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27520/why-cant-there-be-an-error-detecting-code-with-fewer-than-4-qubits)

However there does a exist a $ [[3,1,2]]_3 $ qutrit code with stabilizer generators $ XXX,ZZZ $.

Are there any other qutrit codes with no qubit analogues?