# parameters for which all codes are degenerate

Tags: error-correction

Throughout, assume that $ n,K,d $ are integers such that an $ ((n,K,d)) $ code exists

Recall the quantum Hamming bound: For a non-degenerate ((n,K,d)) qubit code we must have
$$
K(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor} 3^j \binom{n}{j} ) \leq 2^n
$$

If all codes with parameters $ ((n,K,d)) $ are degenerate then must the parameters $ ((n,K,d)) $ violate the quantum Hamming bound?

In other words, are there any parameter $ ((n,K,d)) $ that satisfy the quantum Hamming bound but it is still the case that all $ ((n,K,d)) $ codes are degenerate?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've slightly mis-stated this: you need a $2^K$ instead of $K$.

So, it is true this bound applies rigorously to non-degenerate codes. That **does not** mean that all degenerate codes violate the bound. It just means that there *could* exist degenerate codes that violate it. In fact, most codes that you end up looking at typically do not violate the bound. For example, consider the Shor [[9,1,3]] code. This does not violate the bound.

You might want to check out this previous question: [Violation of the Quantum Hamming bound](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/violation-of-the-quantum-hamming-bound)

Comment: I think my notation is unclear. By $ ((n,K,d)) $ I mean a (possibly nonadditive) code made by encoding a $ K $ dimensional logical space into the physical Hilbert space of $ n $ qubits. So an $ [[n,k,d]] $ stabilizer code is an $ ((n,2^k,d)) $ code since the logical space is size $ 2^k $.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well, whether or not your notation was unclear, I missed that point! (Probably my fault)